# Codeigniter 404 Page Not Found in route with two folders

Tags: codeigniter-3

How do I solve this one in Codeigniter? I am new in MVC framework Codeigniter.

I have three folders in application/views:

- pages

  - dashboard.php
  - members.php
- Starter

  - login.php
  - register.php
- templates

  - header.php
  - footer.php

If I put this code in route:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

I couldn't run my login http://localhost/login - it says 404 Page not found,
but if I remove the route, it worked!

But my http://localhost/members - will redirect on the http://localhost/dashboard if I remove the route:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

And here are my controllers:

**Pages.php**

```php
class Pages extends CI_Controller {
    function view( $page = 'dashboard')
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');

        if( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

**Starter.php**

```php
class Starter extends CI_Controller {
    function view( $page = 'login')
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');

        if( ! file_exists('application/views/starter/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $this->load->view('starter/'.$page);
    }
}
```

How can I fix the issues?
Please help :(

Comment: For a start you do not need to use router. It's better to focus on view, contorller and model. But i will try to explain in a post how it works.

Comment: @StefanAvramovic It seems like a two templates. If  I will leave into the simple route without using the templates it works.

Comment: Yes codeigniter works fine without routes

Comment: Do you have other way yo solve this issues I face now?

Comment: http://localhost/login shuld be  http://localhost/starter/view.  as starter/view = controller/method $this->load->view('starter/login');